# I am trying to create a mcq paper and fetching value from json in adapter radio buttons android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a mcq paper and fetching value from json in adapter radio buttons android want to store the value in array list i have two option true and false but when i click on true its adding the value but after clicking false the position is not getting replaced
i want to store answer in array list

```
public class ExamsQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExamsQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Exam_Question_Fetching> arrayList;
    int j=0;
    ArrayList<String> selectedAnswer=null;
    LayoutInflater inflter;


    public ExamsQuestionAdapter(Context context, List<Exam_Question_Fetching> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        selectedAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            selectedAnswer.add("Not Attempted");
        }

        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExamsQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.exam_question_layout,parent,false);
        return new ExamsQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckBoxValue(){
        //initialize

        return selectedAnswer;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExamsQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Exam_Question_Fetching repo = arrayList.get(position);

       holder.Question.setText(repo.getQuestion());



       holder.buttontrue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked)
               {

                   try {
                       selectedAnswer.add(position, "True");
                   }
                   catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           }
       });

       holder.buttonfalse.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked)
               {
                   try {
                       selectedAnswer.add(position, "false");
                   }
                   catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
               }
           }
       });


       holder.group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkedId) {
                for(int i=0; i<rg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(i);
                    if(btn.getId() == checkedId)
                    {
                        //arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                        //selectedAnswer=new ArrayList<>();
                        /*for (int j=0;j<arrayList.size();j++)
                        {
                            String text = btn.getText().toString();
                            selectedAnswer.set(j,text);
                            Toast.makeText(context,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }*/

                    }
                }
            }
        });




    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView Question,date,type,subname,marks,duration,totalquestion;

        RadioButton buttontrue,buttonfalse;
        RadioGroup group;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Question=itemView.findViewById(R.id.examQuestion);

            buttonfalse=itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_false);
            buttontrue=itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_true);
            group=itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use hashmap to store answer.

Comment: how to replace if state change from true to false

Comment: First get the position from List (arraylist / hashmap) then replace that perticular position with you answer (updated).

Comment: i tried this method i am getting Index out of bound Exception index 0 size 0